# How to add 'div' in pagination using codeigniter

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, pagination

I have a pagination code which is displaying the results in a table format coz that is what i have defined in the code but the problem is that i want to change the code so that i can edit the results and format it in terms of div statements. Pliz assist me in determining where to include the div statement in all the three fields(i.e. course,grade,location) by this i mean e.g. i want my course to have may be a div called mydiv n when it comes to my view i want it to be like this(`<div class="mydiv">course</div>`). I have only uploaded the last section of the pagination page below. I have also included the view where i have called the pagination results.show me where to do that in the view or in simple terms show me how to call each item separately in my view.

Controller for pagination

```
// generate pagination
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $config['base_url'] = site_url('pagination/index/').'/'.$keys.'/';
    $config['per_page'] = $this->limit;
    $config['uri_segment'] = $uri_segment;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    // generate table data      
    $this->load->library('table');
    $this->table->set_empty("&nbsp;");

    $heading = array('No','Course', 'Grade', 'Location');               

    $this->table->set_heading($heading);
    $i = 0 + $offset;
    foreach ($parents as $parent){          
        $this->table->add_row(++$i, $parent->course, $parent->grade, $parent->location);
    }
    $data['table'] = $this->table->generate();      

    // load view
    $this->load->view('paginationview', $data);
```

View

```
<?php echo $pagination; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your config file:

```
        $config['full_tag_open'] = "<div id='pagination'>";
        $config['full_tag_close'] = "</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this in controller

```
 /*for pagination*/
        $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "index.php/dashboard/roomInfo";
    $config["total_rows"] =     $this->dashboard_model->record_count_all_room_registration();
    $config["per_page"] = 5;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

    $config["num_links"] = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="tsc_pagination tsc_paginationA tsc_paginationA01">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['prev_link'] = 'First';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="current"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['first_link'] = '&lt;&lt;';
    $config['last_link'] = '&gt;&gt;';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

   $config['display_pages'] = FALSE;
         $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
          /* pagination ends here */
```

and in view just this

```
    <div class="pagination">
        <?php echo $links; ?>
    </div>
```

then the css goes here

```
           /*for pagination*/
     ul.tsc_pagination { margin:4px 0; padding:0px; overflow:hidden; font:12px 'Tahoma'; list-style-type:none; }
      ul.tsc_pagination li { float:left; margin:0px; padding:0px; margin-left:5px; }

    ul.tsc_pagination li a { color:black; display:block; text-decoration:none; padding:7px 10px 7px 10px; }


     ul.tsc_paginationA li a { color:#FFFFFF; border-radius:3px; -moz-border-radius:3px; -webkit-border-radius:3px; }

      ul.tsc_paginationA01 li a { color:#474747; border:solid 1px #B6B6B6; padding:6px 9px 6px 9px; background:#E6E6E6; background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 1px, #F3F3F3 1px, #E6E6E6); background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, color-stop(0.02, #FFFFFF), color-stop(0.02, #F3F3F3), color-stop(1, #E6E6E6)); }
   ul.tsc_paginationA01 li:hover a,
     ul.tsc_paginationA01 li.current a { background:#FFFFFF; }
    .pagination
{
margin: 0px; color: #3399ff; width:100%;
    }
  /*pagination css ends up*/
```